# Azure Invoke Device Module method using REST API

Tags: azure, postman, azure-api-management

I want to use the Invoke Device Module API from Azure, where I want to send a payload using the API, which will be responsible for sending message from cloud to the module. I am following this article "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/digitaltwinmodel/service/invokedevicemodulemethod"

I am using postman to execute this API, but I am getting the following response. 
[image]

I have added 2 headers in postman 1] Authorization in this I have added a bearerToken and 2] content-type as application/json.  I am giving a payload in the body section. Please let me know what could be wrong here, or if I need to configure it in some different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how it is done. 
All we need to do is use the SAS Token in the authorization header instead of bearerToken and use the following body.

```
{
"methodName": "name_of_your_method",
"responseTimeoutInSeconds": 60,
 "payload": {
    "command": "your_message"}
}
```

The API URL is the following POST method

```
"https://fully-qualified-iothubname.azure-devices.net/twins/{deviceId}/modules/{moduleId}/methods?api-version=2019-07-01-preview"
```

Use the following command to generate SAS Token and FYI SAS Token expires after 1 hour of generation:

```
az iot hub generate-sas-token -n Ageye
```

This works perfectly fine and gives the following response:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "payload": {
        "status": "ok"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a double slash in URL http://azure-devices.net//twins. Can you please try with correct http://azure-devices.net/twins/

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I updated it, but still the error is same.